# error: 'VD<Class1> Class2::data' is private within this context

Tags: c++

I'm having some problems with my code. I declared in the .h two friend functions which are:

```
 #ifndef CLASS2_H

#define CLASS2_H

#include "class1.h"

#include <string>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Class2{

private:


  VD<Class1> data;    //Vector of objects of Class1


  VD<int> number;      //Vector of int

public:

   Constructor();

   friend istream & operator >> (istream & i, const Class1 & other);


   friend ostream & operator << (ostream &o, const Class1 & other);


 };
 #endif
```

And the .cpp is:

```
  istream &  operator >> (istream & i,Class2 & other){
    string n;
    Class1 ing;

    getline(i,n);

    while(!i.eof()){
      i >> ing;
      otro.data.Insert(ing,otro.data.size()-1);
   }

   return i;
}


  ostream &  operator << (ostream &o, const Ingredientes & otro){

      for(int i = 0; i < otro.datos.size(); i++){
        o << other.data[i];
  }
return o;
```

}

So, the error that I'm getting is:
error: 'VD Class2::data' is private within this context. I declared the functions of operator >> y << friend but I doesn't make any sense that compiler says to me that I can't access to the private data. Any help please?

Comment: Can you please extract a [mcve] and format that consistently? As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Your code seems to have bugs, so I'm amazed that it compiles at all.. `o << other.data[i];` should give an error. And I love `otro.data.Insert(ing, otro.data.size() - 1);` xD reinventing `push_back`.

Comment: You declared `operator>>` for `Class1` as friend, but the implementation shows `operator>>` for `Class2` Typo? Also please use a proper IDE to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be very new at C++, and you seem to be doing quite complex things, while you're not understanding the basics yet. Please find a tutorial or so.

A few things:

- `using namespace std;` is -especially in a header- never a good idea. It's like you're going on holiday, but bring along everything in your house. Refer to standard namespace functions using `std::`.
- an `istream& operator>>()` cannot put anything in an object that is declared `const`.
- using `vec.insert(obj, vec.size()-1)` is reinventing one of the most essential funcitons of `std::vector`: `push_back()`...
- `while (!i.eof())` is not good, because `eof` is not set until *after* the read past the end.
- there's no `string& operator>>(string& str, Class1& obj)` function defined. We have `std::stringstream` for that.

To show how you *could* realize some of this, I'm going to write some example code. Please don't just copy it, but try to understand it.

test.txt

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

main.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

template <typename T>
using VD = std::vector<T>;

class Class1 {
private:
    int d;
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& i, Class1& obj) {
        i >> obj.d;
        return i;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const Class1& obj) {
        o << obj.d;
        return o;
    }
};

class Class2 {
private:
    VD<Class1> data{};    //Vector of objects of Class1
public:
    void Clear() { data.clear(); }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& i, Class2& obj) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(i, line);
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        Class1 ing;
        while (iss >> ing) {
            obj.data.push_back(ing);
        }
        return i;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const Class2& obj) {
        for (auto const& cl1 : obj.data) {
            o << cl1 << " ";
        }
        return o;
    }
};

int main() {
    Class2 cl2;

    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("test.txt");
    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        ifs >> cl2;
    }
    std::cout << "first line: " << cl2 << '\n';

    cl2.Clear();

    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        ifs >> cl2;
    }
    std::cout << "second line: " << cl2 << '\n';

    ifs.close();
}
```